# Infinite Lebesgue integral and sequences

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue-measurable function such that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $f.$ If 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx < C,$$ 
for $C < \infty$ a fixed constant, why does there have to be a sequence $\{x_i\}$ such that $x_i$ goes to infinity, and $f(x_i)+f(-x_i) \to 0$ as $i \to \infty?$

If $f$ is continuous, this is clear.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f=\int_{0}^{\infty}f+\int_{-\infty}^0f=\int_{0}^{\infty}(f(x)+f(-x))$. If there is $K,M>0$ such that $f(x)+f(-x)>K$ for $x>M$. Then $\int_{0}^{\infty}(f(x)+f(-x))\geq \int_{M}^{\infty}K=\infty$. Therefore, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $x_n\in (n,\infty)$ such that $0\leq f(x_n)+f(-x_n)< 1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

If such a sequence doesn't exist, it means that there exist $\delta>0$ and $R\geq0$  with $f(x)+f(-x)\geq\delta$ for all $x\geq R$. Then
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}f=\int_{[0,\infty)}f(x)+f(-x)\geq\int_{[R,\infty)}f(x)+f(-x)\geq\delta\,m([R,\infty))=\infty.
$$